# My Dell latitude d610 will not boot up

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

I have a Dell latitude d610 which for some odd reason will not boot up or let me reinstall Windows 7. It keep asking me to load drivers but is not showing any drivers to load.

I tried putting Windows XP and it tells me that there are no bootable devices.

Please help me fix it.

Comment: I wish we could wave a magic wand and help you my friend, but we need a lot more information that that.  You will need to tell us exactly what steps you take to make the error occur, the exact wording of the error, and even some screenshots of the problem would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Download this [Dell diagnostics bootable CD ISO image](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R133063&SystemID=LAT_PNT_PM_D610&servicetag=&os=WW1&osl=en&deviceid=3841&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=5&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=13&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=176977), burn it to a CD as an Image (not data) and then boot from the CD you made and run the full diagnostics on your hardware, see if anything fails the tests.

You may have a failed hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking out the Windows 7 installation FAQ? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Windows-7-installation-problems-frequently-asked-questions

Although from your brief description, it sounds like it could possibly be something more than just a software problem, but this is just a guess based on what you've written.